# C++ Converting to String eventually stops working

Tags: c++, string

The below method is called every second 4 times, for a while it works fine, I get the following output:

```
++++++++++++++++
^
^
++++++++++++++++
```

However after a few hundred calls, the line

```
String str = String(tosend);
```

Seems to stop working somehow and I get the output

```
++++++++++++++++

^
++++++++++++++++
```

So for whatever reason 'str' has no value. As I'm typing this it seems if I leave the application running long enough it starts working again and I get the correct output. What on earth is wrong here? I'm baffled.

```
void Transmit(char tosend)
{
    String str = String(tosend);
    const char *tosend_ready = str.c_str();
    Serial.println("++++++++++++++++");
    Serial.println(str);
    Serial.println(tosend);
    Serial.println("++++++++++++++++");
    vw_send((uint8_t *)tosend_ready, strlen(tosend_ready));
    vw_wait_tx();
    delay(100);

}
```

Comment: what are those weird `String` objects? C++ only has `std::string`.

Comment: `assert(tosend == '^');` and wait for it to fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've no idea what `String` is, but this implementation can get you rid of it (looks like embedded anyway, so you shouldn't care about C-isms... right?)

```
void Transmit(char tosend)
{
    const char buf[2] = { tosend, '\0' };

    Serial.println("++++++++++++++++");
    Serial.println(buf);
    Serial.println(tosend);
    Serial.println("++++++++++++++++");
    vw_send(buf, 2);
    vw_wait_tx();
    delay(100);

}
```